# how to get the latest value in Oracle SQL when using join and groupBY

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT A.CreateDatetime,B.OrderNumber from WORKORDER A 
join UPGD B on A.phonenumber=B.number 
where B.ACCOUNTNUMBER in 
(select ACCOUNTNUMBER,CreateDatetime 
 from UPGD group BY ACCOUNTNUMBER, CreateDatetime 
HAVING COUNT(ACCOUNTNUMBER)=1 
ORDER BY CreateDatetime desc)
and ROWNUM='1'
order by A.CreateDatetime desc;
```

table : WORKORDER

```
---------------------------------------------
CreateDatetime    ACCOUNTNUMBER    phonenumber
6/17/2018           12345678        3423423534
6/16/2018           87655432        1232412344
5/20/2018           84534523        3424234234
```

table : UPGD

```
---------------------------------------------
CreateDatetime    ACCOUNTNUMBER    phonenumber
6/17/2018           12345678        3423423534
6/17/2018           12345678        3423423534
6/16/2018           87655432        1232412344
5/20/2018           84534523        3424234234
```

i am trying to join two table and get fields which have only 1 Accountnumber and only want the latest fields

When i using the above query i am getting below error

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Add the expected data of the sample data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL query
your first mistake is in join second condition

because *B.ACCOUNTNUMBER* should check with *one column* not *two column*

and why not use where clause instead of on condtions

```
    SELECT A.CreateDatetime,B.OrderNumber from WORKORDER as A 
    join UPGD B on A.phonenumber=B.number 
    where B.ACCOUNTNUMBER in 
                     (select ACCOUNTNUMBER from UPGD group BY ACCOUNTNUMBER,CreateDatetime
                            HAVING COUNT(ACCOUNTNUMBER) = 1 
                                            ORDER BY CreateDatetime desc)
    and ROWNUM='1'
    order by A.CreateDatetime desc;
```